# The <split/> element may not appear on a <job/> with abstract="true" spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have different jobs which needs to share split (multiple steps running in parallel) from parenet job.  Below is configuration

```
<job id="parentJob" abstract="true">

    <split id="split1" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor">
        <flow>
            <step id="step0_1">
                <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <chunk reader="step0_1ItemReader" writer="step0_1ItemWriter"
                        commit-interval="1000" />
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step0_2">
                <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <chunk reader="step0_2ItemReader" writer="step0_2ItemWriter"
                        commit-interval="1000" />
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step0_3">
                <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <chunk reader="step0_2ItemReader" writer="step0_2ItemWriter"
                        commit-interval="1000" />
                </tasklet>
            </step>
        </flow>

    </split>

</job>


<job id="job1" parent="parentJob">
    <step id="step1_1" next="split1">
        <tasklet ref="step1_1Tasklet" />
    </step>
</job>




<job id="job2" parent="parentJob">
    <step id="step2_1" next="split1">
        <tasklet ref="step2_1Tasklet" />
    </step>
</job>
```

I am getting this error

The  element may not appear on a  with abstract="true" spring batch

How do I share common split from parent between different jobs or How can we use standalone split elements like step element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<split/>` element is akin to a step in Spring Batch.  While it's not a step, it is a state of a batch job.  States are not inheritable in Spring Batch because there is no way to know what the order would be.  If jobA had a split in it and jobB had three steps and inherited jobA, where would the split go?  At the beginning?  At the end?

The best way to handle common flows like this is to externalize a flow and reference it from within your job.  For example (this example has a flow with steps, but it can contain a split as well):

```
<job id="job">
    <flow id="job1.flow1" parent="flow1" next="step3"/>
    <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
</job>

<flow id="flow1">
    <split id="split1">
        <flow>
            <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2"/>
            <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
</flow>
```

You can read more about externalized flows in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#external-flows